# Ubuntu 18.04.2 onboard NIC stops working after update

Tags: networking

A recent OS update (maybe within the last 2 weeks) seems to have rendered my onboard network switch to no longer work. Things were working great for many years since. Until I can get my on-board NIC to work again I've been using an USB NIC which thankfully will come up with DHCP by default but it would be really great if we would just use my onboard nic again. I've been applying every OS install in hopes that one of these installs will fix my issue. Can anyone advise on how to get my On-board nic working again?

here is an edited output of the lspci command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82574L Gigabit Network Connection
0c:00.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation DSL6540 USB 3.1 Controller [Alpine Ridge]
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2400 Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
0f:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

If someone can advise on how to get my original nic working again it would be really great. Note that there is a 4 port PCI nic installed in this computer as well so there are six nic including the onboard and the temporary USB nic i'm using. I don't use the 4 port nic because I don't have the PCI covers anymore so am just leaving it in to prevent having a hole in my chassis.

from heynnema's request here are the terminal output of these commands while my usb ethernet cable is plugged in:

```
jchan@jchan-Z170N:/var/lib/filtec$ sudo lshw -C network and cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
Hardware Lister (lshw) - B.02.18
usage: lshw [-format] [-options ...]
       lshw -version

    -version        print program version (B.02.18)

format can be
    -html           output hardware tree as HTML
    -xml            output hardware tree as XML
    -json           output hardware tree as a JSON object
    -short          output hardware paths
    -businfo        output bus information

options can be
    -class CLASS    only show a certain class of hardware
    -C CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -c CLASS        same as '-class CLASS'
    -disable TEST   disable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -enable TEST    enable a test (like pci, isapnp, cpuid, etc. )
    -quiet          don't display status
    -sanitize       sanitize output (remove sensitive information like serial numbers, etc.)
    -numeric        output numeric IDs (for PCI, USB, etc.)
    -notime         exclude volatile attributes (timestamps) from output

jchan@jchan-Z170N:/var/lib/filtec$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I can certainly ping 8.8.8.8 while the USB Ethernet is on as this is how I am able to visit askubuntu.com. i'll follow up with the results of them while the USB Ethernet is not plugged in.

Comment: Are you able to `ping 8.8.8.8`? Edit your question and show me `sudo lshw -C network` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @heynnema I just rebooted twice and now its working. Not sure what fixed it. I've had many reboots since this but I'd like to know if something did fix it.

Comment: There were actually 3 separate commands in my previous comment. It looks like you combined the first 2 into one command, and that's why it didn't work. Can you please try the first two commands again, and then re-edit your question with the corrected output?